# FOSUserBundle not found in appkernel

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony on Windows and I tried to configure FOSUserBundle as described in the official documentation.

I get this error when try to update the schema:

```
Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in app/AppKernel.php line 20;
```

searched for the problem and find this solution:
adding this to autoload.php

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    //all the rest
    'FOS' => $vendor_dir . '/bundles',
));
```

but it returns another error which says

```
call to undefined method ...\ClassLoader::RegisterNamespace() in ...\autoload.php on line 13
```

can anybody plz tell me what should i do?:|

and this is my appkernel.php file:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Sad\Bundle\WarehouseBundle\SadWarehouseBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        );

       if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: What symfony version are you using? It has been a long time since we had to register the namespaces manually. Have you downloaded the vendor script using composer?

Comment: i'm using the latest version which is 2.3
and also using composer to dl and install the bundles.

Comment: Is there a a {YOUR_PROJECT_PATH}\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle folder?

Comment: yes,It's there and it contains the FOSUserBundle.php file

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what's happening. Can you edit your question and add the content of your AppKernel.php?

Comment: tnx for your helping...i've added the appkernel

Comment: This should be working as intended. Please try running `php composer.phar self-update`, `php composer.phar update`, removing your manual namespace registry and clearing your cache (`php app/console cache:clear`). If it doesn't work, we can get a workaround manually adding the bundle to the loader. Let's give it one more try, though.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I found out that the FOSUserBundle was not properly installed. You should delete your **/vendor/friendsofsymfony/** directory and then update the bundle using:

```
php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

It worked for me. I hope it helps someone else having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, there seems to be nothing wrong with your code.

Before we can get on the workarounds, let's try to reinstall your bundle, through the following steps:

- Remove that `$loader->registerNamespaces(...)` thing you added to autoloader.php.
- Run `php composer.phar self-update` to update composer.
- Remove the line `use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),` from AppKernel.php.
- Run `php composer.phar update` to update all your bundles.
- Clear your cache, running `php app/console cache:clear`.
- Add the line `use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),` to AppKernel.php again.

Those should do it. If you still can't use the bundle and you need the workaround (which I wouldn't advice), this is the way to go:

Open app/autoload.php. Right after `$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php`. add the following:

```
//Loads FOSUserBundle
$loader->add('FOS', __DIR__.'/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS');
```

Again, this should fix the issue and yet is not the correct way to do things. Your bundle should be working.

Comment: tnx for your time...
but it doesn't change:(
I had another project which works well without this problem...i'm going to modify it...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error in `Symfony 3.x`.

If `composer` can not be executed and you can only transfer the files by `FTP`, it's necessary to update the file:

`vendor/composer`

and maybe

`vendor/symfony` (if the version is updated)

The same solution applies to this error

> Fatal error: Class 'FOS \ JsRoutingBundle \ FOSJsRoutingBundle' not
>   found