# Symfony 2 FOSUserBundle problems

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I'm working in symfony 2 and I'm trying to use `FOSUserBundle` but I can't resolve this problem : help plz

```
[LogicException]                                                             
  Bundle "BlogUserBundle" extends bundle "FOSUserBundle", 
  which is not registered.  




<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Blog\UserBundle\BlogUserBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you haven't registered your bundle in `AppKernel.php`, could you check it one more time ?

Comment: i have already do it,
This is my kernel

Comment: Could you edit your question adding the code of your AppKernel::registerBundles method?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forget to add `new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()`, app/AppKernel.php registerBundles method.

Comment: i did it too, new Blog\UserBundle\BlogUserBundle(), beacause my new bundle is in src->Blog->UserBundle

Answer (score 0):

Add `new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),` after your line `new AppBundle\AppBundle(),` in app/AppKernel.php.

Comment: i got this ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle" in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\nomProjet\app\AppKernel.php line 20. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

Comment: The bundle is in your vendors ?

Comment: yes in my vendor in this structure : vendor->friendsofsymfony->user-bundle

Comment: Follow these steps, it may help you
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: No.
Can you paste properly your AppKernel.php file updated with the FOSUserBundle registration ?

Comment: That's better. 
With this AppKernel, do you still have the ClassNotFoundException ?
What's your AppBundle\AppBundle() ?
Did you install FOSUserBundle with composer ?

Comment: yes i installed, non i have this : FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot load resource "@AppBundle/Controller/". Make sure the "AppBundle/Controller/" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.

Comment: It means that your AppBundle isn't registered properly. 
Does this seems ok to you ? `new AppBundle\AppBundle(),`
Doesn't it should be `new App\Bundle\AppBundle(),`  ?

Comment: yes it's ok because my AppBundle is in : src->AppBundle and my class ->AppBundle, i just  add in the Appkernel.php
new \AppBundle\AppBundle(), 
And now i got this :ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle" in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\nomProjet\app\AppKernel.php line 20. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

Comment: the problem i think is in this line because in the vendor the stucture is : friendsofsymfony->user-bundle->command,controller....

but in the appkernel.php : i did : new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()????

Comment: Look at the namespaces, not the structure of the directory.
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserBundle.php
Namespace is `namespace FOS\UserBundle;` and classname is `class FOSUserBundle extends Bundle`

Comment: it's still the same problem :(

Comment: ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle" in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\nomProjet\app\AppKernel.php line 20. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

in this line of my Appkernel.php : new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle

Comment: Can you try those answers ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946989/fosuserbundle-not-found-in-appkernel

update composer / clear cache ..

Comment: i resolve it, i had to update my composer.phar and make some modification, thanks @Ulti